# mongoDb aggregation values as key and value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

my data looks like this:

```
{ "display" : [{
        "SQL commands that triggered the attack:" : ""
      }, {
        "Timetsamp" : "Query:"
      }, [[{
            "ISODate" : "2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z"
          }, "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"], [{
            "ISODate" : "2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z"
          }, "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"], [{
            "ISODate" : "2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z"
          }, "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"]]]
  }
```

how can i make it look like this:

```
"display" : [
{ "SQL commands" : ""}, 
{"Timetsamp" : "Query:"},
{"2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z" : "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"},
{"2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z" : "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"},
{"2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z" : "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"}]
}
```

display in one field from a doc with other fields

Comment: Please, provide a valid JSON.

Comment: now it's valid.

Comment: @J.F. any idea?